# Will there be any problem if we define Uniform Continuity in arbitrary topological space in the following manner?

Tags: general-topology, definition

> **Definition of Uniform Continuity in Arbitrary Topological Space.**  Let $(X,\mathfrak{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{T}_Y)$ be two topological space and let $f:X\to Y$. Then we say $f$ is *uniformly continuous* on $X$ if given an $\mathfrak{T}_Y$-open set $V$ of $Y$ with $f(x),f(y)\in V$, there exists an $\mathfrak{T}_X$-open set $U$ of $X$ such that $x,y\in U$ and $f(U)\subseteq V$.

I think that this definition of Uniform Continuity also implies Continuity and the proof of this immediately follows from the definition of Continuity,

> **Definition of Continuity.**  Let $(X,\mathfrak{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{T}_Y)$ be two topological space and let $f:X\to Y$. Then we say $f$ is *continuous* on $X$ if given an $\mathfrak{T}_Y$-open set $V$ of $Y$ with $f(x)\in V$, there exists an $\mathfrak{T}_X$-open set $U$ of $X$ such that $x\in U$ and $f(U)\subseteq V$.

So, I was wondering what problems will I face if I try to define Uniform Continuity in the manner I did above. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space might be of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Any** continuous function $f:X\to Y$ is "uniformly continuous" according to your definition. Suppose $x,y\in X$ and let $V$ be any open set in $Y$ such that $f(x),f(y)\in V.$ Since $f$ is continuous, the set $U=f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $X$ with $x,y\in U$ and $f(U)\subseteq V.$

It's not just that this particular definition doesn't work. There is no way to define uniform continuity in terms of topologies, because various metrics can be compatible with one and the same topology; and a function can be uniformly continuous with respect to one metric and not uniformly continuous with respect to another metric, although both metrics induce the same topology.

However, you don't quite need a **metric** space to talk about uniform continuity. The most general setting for uniform continuity is [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).

Comment: What if we modify the definition as follows: "Let $(X,\mathfrak{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathfrak{T}_Y)$ be two topological space and let $f:X\to Y$. Then we say $f$ is *uniformly continuous* on $X$ if given an $\mathfrak{T}_Y$-open set $V$ of $Y$, there exists an $\mathfrak{T}_X$-open set $U$ of $X$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V$."?

Comment: Then **every** function will be "uniformly continuous" because $U=\emptyset$ is an open set in $X.$

Comment: I am sorry that I wasn't explicit. I assume that $U\ne \emptyset$.

Comment: Do you also assume that $V\ne\emptyset$?

Comment: Yes. Of course.

Comment: Suppose $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a constant function, say $f(x)=0$ for all $x.$ Let $V$ be the open interval $(1,2).$ There is no nonempty set $U\subset\mathbb R$ such that $f(U)\subseteq V.$